# mapbox setFilter on interval values

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

Trying to apply a map.SetFilter over points with continuous values, grouped by categories like:

0-8000 orange

8000-16000 green.

16000-30000 yellow.

30000-40000 blue.

Bigger than 40000 purple

As example, I want to visualize only values between 8000-16000 and >35000, that is, orange and purple

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/perikut/x1cknef8/6/

Using 'any' gives me all colors. Using 'all' doesn't give me any color. Did not find any similar example around, maybe the formulation of the filter is not correct?

`map.setFilter('hospitals',['any',[">", ["get", "npv_h"], 8000],["<", ["get", "npv_h"], 16000],[">", ["get", "npv_h"], 40000]])`

Also, the first SetTimeout, with the filter below, only partially works. You can still see orange points and I checked that they have a value < 8000

`map.setFilter('hospitals',['any',[">", ["get", "npv_h"], 8000]])`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "purple" was actually another shade of orange so it took a while to understand what you wanted.
Since you want a condition which is either between 8000 and 16000 or higher than 40000, you need another condition within your first timeout.
Adding a `'all'` inside the `'any'` can fix your condition and set those two conditions.

```
 map.setFilter('hospitals',['any',['all',["<", ["get", "npv_h"], 8000],
                     ["<",["get", "npv_h"], 16000]],[">", ["get", "npv_h"], 40000]])
```

Comment: Great, the "['any',['all', piece is what was missing. Really criptic syntax... it would be great any clear doc reference or example explaining this...thanks

Comment: Like i wrote, you have to understand how conditions work for that. what you were looking for was `(condition a + condition b) or (condition c)` and that's what was missing from your syntax.

Comment: yes, i see now that there are 2 arrays into the conditional 'all', each one with different conditions. Got it. Thanks